# How to extract parts of text with XPath and put them in woocommerce attributes as key:value pair?

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to extract words (text) as key:value pair of given XML example:

```
<description>
[Партиден номер]: 2UW01AA [Номер на модела]: HP 14.1 Business Sleeve [Line]: Business [Screen size]: 14.1&quot; [Material]: Polyester [Color]: Black [Dimensions]: [more]
</description>
```

I want result like this:

```
Партиден номер 2UW01AA
Номер на модела HP 14.1 Business Sleeve
Line Business
Screen size 14.1&quot;
Material Polyester
Color Black
```

I want to know Xpath for first and second word as key:value pair to insert in woocommerce attributes.Need two Xpath queries for the result.

```
translate(substring-before(substring-after(//description,"["),": ["),"[]:",codepoints-to-string(10) )
```

This give me the correct output, but i need two Xpath queries, one for the first word and one for the second word.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: translate(substring-before(substring-after(//description,"["),": ["),"[]:",codepoints-to-string(10)  )  this give two words

Comment: Add this to your original post, always

Answer (score 0):

For values (`translate` will return a string with multiple lines, whereas `tokenize` will return a list of strings) :

```
translate(replace(replace(replace(replace(substring-before(normalize-space(//description)," [more"), "\[(.*?)\]:", ";")," ; ",";")," ;",""),"; ",""),";",codepoints-to-string(10))

tokenize(replace(replace(replace(replace(substring-before(normalize-space(//description)," [more"), "\[(.*?)\]:", ";")," ; ",";")," ;",""),"; ",""),";")
```

Output :

```
2UW01AA
HP 14.1 Business Sleeve
Business
14.1"
Polyester
Black
```

For keys :

```
translate(substring-before(substring-after(replace(normalize-space(//description),"\]: (.+?) \[",";"),"["),"]"),";",codepoints-to-string(10))

tokenize(substring-before(substring-after(replace(normalize-space(//description),"\]: (.+?) \[",";"),"["),"]"),";")
```

Output :

```
Партиден номер
Номер на модела
Line
Screen size
Material
Color
Dimensions
```

Note : of course, the preceding expressions could be a lot optimized.

Comment: This working in XPath online tester, but not in WP AllImport plugin. Says "error closing tag" or "unknown function"

Comment: Well, `WP AllImport` does not support XPath 2.0. So `tokenize` and `codepoints-to-string` can't be used. Without it, you can't split your text with line feed. The plugin seems to support PHP. https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/developers/custom-code/inline-php/ So, that could be an option.